# CouchDB Emit with no parameters

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Consider the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  by_author: {
    map: function(doc) {
      if ('authors' in doc) {
        doc.authors.forEach(emit);
      }
    }.toString(),
    reduce: '_count'
  },

  by_subject: {
    map: function(doc) {
      if ('subjects' in doc) {
        doc.subjects.forEach(function(subject){
          emit(subject, subject);

          subject.split(/\s+--\s+/).forEach(function(part){
            emit(part, subject);
          });
        });
      }
    }.toString(),

    reduce: '_count'
  }
};
```

It doesn't look like `doc.authors.forEach(emit);` is valid syntax (or good coding) but it appears to be syntactically correct.

My question is, is *this* shorthand for the following:

```
doc.authors.forEach(function(_doc) {
    emit(_doc.id, _doc);
});
```

If so, is there any benefit to using this shorthand?  How does it work?

Ref. https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Map_Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[emit](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/query-server/javascript.html?highlight=emit#emit) is a function that CouchDB exposes. In JS functions are first-class. (and can be passed as arguments to other functions)

In lieu of explaining all of that, I'll just show you what your code is actually doing. (read up more about functions in JS if you're new)

```
doc.authors.forEach(emit);

doc.authors.forEach(function (item, index, list) {
  emit(author, index, list);
});
```

In JS, the arguments passed to the `forEach` handler fn are:

- the item in the array (ie: `"some user"`)
- the index of that item in the array (eg: `0`)
- the entire array (eg: `[ "some user" ]`)

The `emit()` function only accepts 2 arguments, so the 3rd will simply be ignored. Thus, in the case of a single item array, you will get the equivalent of `emit("some user", 0)`. If there are multiple items, you'll get other emits as well.

Comment: Thanks.  So from a coding perspective, wouldn't it be better to write the latter than the former?  Otherwise, unless you remember that `forEach` will pass three params to `emit` automatically, you'll have to check the documentation before you can understand how the code works.

Comment: Yes, it's far too magical to just pass `emit()` directly, especially since you didn't author it. I would use the more verbose form in your case.